# Duplicate key oiolates unique constraint during signup

Tags: django

> duplicate key value violates unique constraint "auth_user_username_key"
>   DETAIL:  Key (username)=() already exists.

**models.py**

```
class Profile(User):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User)
    mobile = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True, blank=True)
    country_code = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True, blank=True)
    shipping_street_1 = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True, blank=True)
    shipping_street_2 = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True, blank=True)
    shipping_city = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True, blank=True)
    shipping_state = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True, blank=True)
    shipping_country = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True, blank=True)
    shipping_zip = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True, blank=True)
    shipping_tel = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True, blank=True)
    billing_street_1 = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True, blank=True)
    billing_street_2 = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True, blank=True)
    billing_city = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True, blank=True)
    billing_state = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True, blank=True)
    billing_country = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True, blank=True)
    billing_zip = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True, blank=True)
    billing_tel = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True, blank=True)
```

**views.py**

```
class SignUpView(FormView):
    model = models.User
    template_name = "registration/signup.html"
    form_class = forms.SignupForm
    success_url = "/"

    @method_decorator(csrf_exempt)
    def dispatch(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        return super(SignUpView, self).dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)

    def form_valid(self, form):
        e = models.User.objects.filter(email=self.request.POST.get("signup_email")).first()
        if e is None:
            user_obj, created = \
                u = models.User.objects.get_or_create(
                email=self.request.POST.get("signup_email"),
                username=self.request.POST.get("signup_email"),
            )
            user_obj.set_password(self.request.POST.get("signup_password"))
            user_obj.save()
            login(self.request, user_obj)

            models.Profile.objects.create(
                user=user_obj,
                mobile=self.request.POST.get("signup_mobile"),
                country_code=self.request.POST.get("signup_country_code")
            )
        return super(SignUpView, self).form_valid(form)
```

It works the first time but database entry is blank. Second time it gives this error.

**forms.py**

```
class SignupForm(forms.Form):
    signup_email = forms.EmailField(required=True)
    signup_password = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput, required=True)
    signup_confirm_password = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput, required=True)
    signup_first_name = forms.CharField(required=True)
    signup_last_name = forms.CharField(required=True)
    signup_country_code = forms.CharField(required=True)
    signup_mobile = forms.CharField()

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(SignupForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['signup_email'].widget.attrs.update({'placeholder': "Email"})
        self.fields['signup_password'].widget.attrs.update({'placeholder': 'Password'})
        self.fields['signup_confirm_password'].widget.attrs.update({'placeholder': 'Confirm Password'})
        self.fields['signup_first_name'].widget.attrs.update({'placeholder': "First Name"})
        self.fields['signup_last_name'].widget.attrs.update({'placeholder': "Last Name"})
        self.fields['signup_country_code'].widget.attrs.update({'placeholder': "Country Code"})
        self.fields['signup_mobile'].widget.attrs.update({'placeholder': "Mobile Number"})

    def clean_signup_confirm_password(self):
        if self.cleaned_data.get('signup_password') and self.cleaned_data.get('signup_password'):
            if self.cleaned_data.get('signup_password') != self.cleaned_data.get('signup_confirm_password'):
                raise forms.ValidationError("The two password fields must match.")
        return self.cleaned_data['signup_confirm_password']
```

Comment: Your problem is that you are trying to create `User` with empty `username` twice. `username` field should be unique for each user. Add your form code

Comment: we have uploaded the forms.py file as asked.

Comment: First clean your code: you have `self.model`, but using models.User. You're not using the form.cleaned_data in form_valid, but going to request.POST. Are you actually submitting the form through POST?

Comment: yes, the form is submitted through POST. How, to resolve this issue? I've just started working on django so not technically sound.

Answer (score 0):

Try editing your view somewhat like this,

```
def form_valid(self, form):
    email = form.cleaned_data['signup_email']
    password = form.cleaned_data['signup_password']
    user, created = models.User.objects.get_or_create(username=email, email=email)           
    if created: 
        user.set_password(password)
        user.save()
        models.Profile.objects.create(
            user=user,
            mobile=form.cleaned_data["signup_mobile"],
            country_code=form.cleaned_data["signup_country_code"]
        )
    user_obj = authenticate(username=user.username, password=user.password)
    if user is not None:
        login(self.request, user_obj)            
    return super(SignUpView, self).form_valid(form)
```

Comment: But the Username field is required.

Comment: I've tried adding a print statement using get.POST and it gets print in the terminal.Why its not assigning the Username field?

Comment: Using request.POST is not good practice. When django forms are used, they provides the necessary validations​ in the posted data.

Comment: e can never be None. Why would you want to be None. Forms does that kind of validations.

Comment: Yes, but that's why the model filling code never ever hits.

Comment: **Profile.user must be a User instance.** Although the data entry is being created and i can even login with the new signup i made.

Comment: Is the new signup view exactly like in my answer??

Comment: I have edited my answer... check it out!! also, make sure the user is logging in...

Comment: guys, its solved... None of us noticed the models correctly.  **class Profile(models.Model)**